# Tomcat lockup on shutdown

Tags: .net, windows, tomcat, tomcat8

Edit: The Issues were not caused by eclipse or eclipse photon, but by a .Net-Update, which was installed around the same time. If you are looking at this Question because you have similar issues, please check, if you installed such an update recently.

I have recently installed eclipse photon and am using an existing workspace from oxygen. To debug the web-project I am working on, I am starting the tomcat8-server instance out of eclipse (server-view). This has worked in the past, and actually works now as well. However, when restarting the server or terminating it, the javaw.exe tomcat seems to run on is still running and cannot be terminated (not even as administrator).
The reason (according to my research) seems to be that the process holds write privileges on a file system, and therefore cannot be safely terminated. My only option so far is to restart the entire (windows) system.

I have tried so far:

- ending the process tree (both as base user and admin) -> access denied
- ending the process (both as base user and admin) -> access denied
- terminating the process from the shell (cmd and cygwin - both as base user and admin) -> Could not be terminated... No instance running (I am translating this from german, so the wording might be slightly different)

It seems like the eclipse hook into tomcat somehow fails to properly terminate the tomcat process, leaving it crippled and interminable. In this mode, the ports the server occupies remain blocked for other processes, so restarting tomcat will result in an error: "'Starting ...' has encountered a problem. Several ports (...) required by ... are already in use. [...]" and so forth.

**Did anyone experience that same problem, and/or has found a solution?**

To clarify: I am not looking for a way to force-stop the broken process, which seems impossible. I am looking for a solution to not have the server crash irreparably in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As users Cathy and pke have pointed out, a Windows-update (More specifically a .Net-Update) was the culprit for the issues at hand. After uninstalling the update KB4087364 (I am running Win 7), the problem vanished.
The update seems to cause the following problem:

```
Addresses an issue that occurs when an administrator tries to stop the World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC). The W3SVC remains in a "stopping" state, but cannot fully stop or it cannot be restarted.
```

It remains to note, that there seems to be a fix for this issue with "KB4338821", which I have not tested. It can be downloaded here: http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4338821
<strike>As I have not taken this way myself, I can only link the update, not guarantee success.</strike>
I have now tested this, and it works perfectly for me!

Answer (score 3):

Having what sounds like a similar issue.  Issue began Saturday after Windows updates were installed.  Running Tomcat 8.5 on Windows Server 2012 R2 and 2008 R2 SP1.  Doesn't affect all servers and still unsure of the root cause.  Did find a correlation with all servers experiencing the problem though.  System eventID 16002, source AFD, gets triggered when Tomcat is stopped.  Once Tomcat is started again, web app can't be displayed. Can't even display http://localhost:8080 on the app server. Only fix is to restart the server. Still working to identify a solution. Do you see these same AFD log entries?  Did you recently install updates? Look forward to hearing your thoughts.

Comment: thank you for restoring my beliefe in my sanity. I was starting to think I was doing something terribly wrong. I will attempt to isolate the update in question and roll back on it.

Answer (score 2):

Also having what sounds like a similar issue.

Issue began tuesday 24th July on 2 differents servers:
Tomcat 7 on Windows Server 2012 R2
Websphere CE 2.1.1 (based on Apache Tomcat 6.0.33 I think) on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

On Windows Server 2012 R2, the last Windows update was 11th July and today 25th July.
On the Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 I had some Windows update sunday 22th July (another scheduled for 29th July).

On Windows Server 2012 R2, Event ID: 16002, source AFD.

> Closing a TCP socket with local port number 8080 in process 7660 is taking longer than expected. The local port number may not be available until the close operation is completed. This happens typically due to misbehaving network drivers. Ensure latest updates are installed for Windows and any third-party networking software including NIC drivers, firewalls, or other security products.

(translated from french)

On the Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 : Event ID: 7011 "Timeout (30000 milliseconds) waiting for a transaction response from the service" (translated from french)

Like you and Cathy I can not stop the process. 
On Windows Server 2012 R2 there is no running process, but all the Tomcat ports are in use. 
On the Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 I can not stop the process (through the cmd line or task manager).

Onky workaround I found so far is to restart Windows.
EDIT: Windows Update fix "KB4338821" worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Glad I found this thread. I was struggling hard to fix the issue.
It seems KB4338821 is not applicable for Windows server 2012 and 2012R2. Just looked up on MS site and here are KBs available for respective OS:
Windows 2012 R2: KB4338831 - https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4338831/july172018kb4338831osbuildpreviewofmonthlyrollup
Windows 2012: KB4338816 - https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4338816/july172018kb4338816osbuildpreviewofmonthlyrollup

FYI, I am planning to install these patches tonight on my server. Fingers crossed that the patches will fix the issue for me. Would keep everyone posted.